# Marketing Cloud interactive email to include a catch-all triggered send upon successful submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, interactive-email

We're rolling out a campaign with an interactive email trial included, inviting customer's who we've identified as having a non-communicating meter (we're a utility provider) the opportunity to submit a meter read or have a technician inspect the meter (no cost involved). Historically, we would have directed traffic to a landing page hosted on our website, with a submit action to trigger an email to a company employee with the submission details to follow up / review prior to data loading work (not the best, I know but we're on the path to automation).

My immediate thought was to writeback to the interactive form DE with a default staff email address and use this in a triggered send. Looking around, I can't find anything that hints at how to achieve it otherwise. I was wondering if anyone had given this a go and had any words of wisdom?

So what I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Send customers' an interactive email
2. Record the customers' submission detail
3. Direct these customers' to the success page
4. Send an internal email to a data loader with the detail captured at submission

I have steps 1 - 3 sorted, just unsure about how to achieve the fourth step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a triggered send to be sent upon the form being submitted/page loading. If the staff email address is a default email address you could just hard code it into the Ampscript triggered send code. You can find more details for creating triggered sends here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/29/send-a-triggered-email-using-ampscript/